# Error in ugarchfit mean(data)==0

Tags: r

I am fitting my ugarchspec into the ugarchfit-function, but get the error concerning the mean(data) == 0.

How should I modify my data to so that this error does not occur?

```
 myfit<-ugarchfit(spec=myspec, data=mydata2, out.sample = 0, solver = "solnp", solver.control = list(), 
                      fit.control = list(stationarity = 1, fixed.se = 0, scale = 0, rec.init = 'all'), 
                      numderiv.control = list(grad.eps=1e-4, grad.d=0.0001, 
                                              grad.zero.tol=sqrt(.Machine$double.eps/7e-7), hess.eps=1e-4, hess.d=0.1, 
                                              hess.zero.tol=sqrt(.Machine$double.eps/7e-7), r=4, v=2))


Error in if (mean(data) == 0) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Here is a sample of the data

```
structure(c(0.00857284996420482, -0.0214828379001606, 0.0493759635676962, 
0.0593643780418613, -0.0260971572816295, -0.0718686084701758, 
0.00959593733451847,..., -0.0119433191489424, 0, NA), .Dim = c(1674L, 
1L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, "Return"))
```

It contains a total of 1700 rows.

Comment: You will need to give us an idea of what mydata2 looks like, using `dput(mydata2)` would be the best way to get a copy of the data that you can include in the post

Comment: I edited my question and added a sample of the data.

Comment: Not an answer because the question still isn't reproducible, but the `NA` in your data is likely to be the cause